# Cutoff parameter in Gurobi - does it help with solve time at all?

Tags: gurobi

Does the Cutoff parameter in Gurobi do anything other than prohibit returning solutions below/above the cutoff value?

I ask in particular because I have a maximization MIP where I am trying to find a solution of at least X (don't care if it's optimal, just X or higher).  Gurobi has previously found incumbent solutions of 0.8X, with an upper bound of 1.1X, before failing to improve.

So I know that 0.8X is attainable, is there any benefit to setting Cutoff to 0.8X?  Would that speed up the solve time at all to get to an incumbent > 0.8X?

Comment: In addition to what @fontanf recommends (hot-starting from the 0.8X solution), you might want to set the MIPFocus parameter to 1, which focuses on finding (improved) feasible solutions.

Comment: @prubin I'm using R ( ompr and ROI.plugin.gurobi ), do you know if it's possible to provide a starting solution to Gurobi using ompr?

Comment: I'm not certain, but I don't think so. I don't see any provision in ompr for it. Dirk Schumacher, the author of ompr, is working on a newer library ("rmpk"), and there he has creation of a method for providing starting solutions as an open issue. Also, ompr relies on the ROI library, and I don't see anything about starting solutions in the ROI documentation. You might contact the author(s) of ROI and ask them.

Comment: thanks @prubin.  I didn't think so either but I know you've used ompr.  (Great blog post on it a while back!)  I love being able to model MIPs in R with flexibility and ease using ompr, but I would definitely appreciate some more features and control in its use

Comment: Thanks! Same here. I'm not sure, but I think Dirk's switch to the rmpk package may be motivated more by speed/model size concerns than by new features.

Comment: Indeed, I'm using MILPModel .  It builds the models fast, even huge ones, but the syntax is an acquired taste and I wish I could use the more intuitive syntax of a MIPModel

Answer (score 3):

Yes, if the solver doesn't use a pure "best bound" strategy as selection rule, then setting a cutoff might make it possible to prune some nodes which wouldn't have been pruned otherwise. So, in theory, it should slightly speed up the resolution. In practice, one can never be sure of what will happen though.

However, if you already have a solution, it's better to provide the solution directly than to give its value as cutoff.